# Can this boost::lambda: var(n)=n; be rewritten by using C++11 lambda?

Tags: c++

When I was reading Christopher M.Kohlhoff's blog, I stumbled upon the following code piece:

```
    asio::error_code ec[max_clients];
    int n = -1;

    yield acceptor.async_accept(
                *socket[n],
                unlambda((
                  var(n) = n,
                  var(ec[n]) = _1
                )));
```

This line of code: var(n) = n seems to achieve the "save and restore" effect. Can it be rewritten by using C++11 lambda?

Edit:

According to boost lambda's official documents, var(n) is a function object and returns reference to n when invoked, and the right-hand side n is captured by value. The effect is that when the lambda is created, the current value of `n` is saved in the lambda. When the lambda executes, the variable `n` is assigned the previously-captured value, effectively "restoring the saved value".

Comment: Could you elaborate upon what you mean by "the 'save and restore' effect"? There might be some people who stumble upon this question without being able to read your mind (nor have read the blog, if that's where you got the term from). Not to mention that writing code from functional specs gives greater freedom in what can be done than trying to transform code directly.

Comment: @JaMiT OK, question edited.

Comment: The C++14 syntax for this would be `lambda = [&, saved_n = n](auto&& v) { n = saved_n; ec[n] = v; }`. C++11 syntax would be `int saved_n = n; lambda = [&, saved_n](int v) { n = saved_n; ec[n] = v; }` (I'm guessing that n and v are ints.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Ah, i see, one level of indirection. thanks.